# Where to ask if anyone knows a similar JavaScript Gallery I have seen on a website?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I need to find a JavaScript gallery script like the one I have seen on a website.

Where should I ask if someone knows a similar looking gallery script?

Comment: Short answer is there is no good place to ask for libraries on SE. longer answe is, if you read their help files thoroughly, search their meta for highly-upvoted Qs on how to ask good questions, and craft a post carefully, you might get an answer on Softwarerecs.se. But if you just go and bang a question like this up, it’ll be closed post haste.

Comment: What my above neighbour said, though you can always try to ask in chat.

Answer (score 2):

The [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) site accepts questions about [programming tools, frameworks and libraries](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8/23377), provided that they meet their [quality guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/23377). This is an option when you just want to have *a* library meeting certain requirements.

If instead you want to know which library is used by that website, e.g. an *identification* question, that would be a bad fit for any Stack Exchange website. An option would be to check which JavaScript files are being loaded when you visit the page. Their name or content could give away which library it is, especially if you Google around a bit.

Comment: Looks like the OP asks for an "identify this" type of question. Those won't go well, in general.

Comment: That's not how I read it, but maybe I put too much emphasis on the word 'similar'.